# iOS Detecting if a class is Objective-C or Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-runtime

I'm working on an internal tool (something that will never be submitted to the App Store) and I'd like to detect at run time if a class is Objective-C or Swift. Is this possible?

Comment: What's the goal here? If you find out that a particular class is Objective-C or Swift, what are you planning to do with that information?

Comment: This is an XY problem.  What are you *actually* trying to do and why?

Comment: I'd like to know if it's possible just to satisfy my own curiosity.

Comment: All classes in ObjC inherit from `NSObject` so that's one tell sign. But Swift classes can inherit from `NSObject` too. Now, if a Swift class extend an ObjC, how wold you categorize the first one?

Comment: Yeah, what would an ObjC class derived from a Swift class derived from an ObcJ class be? :)

Comment: It is convention for every class in Objective-C to inherit from NSObject, in Mac and iOS programming.  But it is not necessary for a class to inherit from NSObject.

Comment: at runtime it seems impossible, since they are just sub class of a common base. But, if you are saying a tool that is not inside of the app, what you can do is search all the files with .swift, and seach the class def pattern and the name

Comment: FYI - Not all classes have to inherit from `NSObject` in Objective-C. Some classes can have a root class of `NSProxy` (though this isn't very common).

Comment: @rmaddy and some classes, like NSAtom, the anti-null, are root classes all to themselves.

Answer (score 9):

If, for academic purposes, you **absolutely** must know if a class was created in swift code or not (and not in a way that can easily be fooled via `objc_allocateClassPair`), then you *can* utilize the information that can be found in [`objc-runtime-new.h`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-647/runtime/objc-runtime-new.h), specifically, the flags related to `FAST_IS_SWIFT`.

To extract these flags without having to make your source code C++ or fight with including a ton of private headers, you *can* use something similar to the following, but please note: **THIS IS SUPER FRAGILE**.

This is probably not ABI-enforced anywhere, and any future version can change this without consequence. Bear that in mind, etc., etc.

Without further ado, the crazy hack ensues:

```
#define FAST_IS_SWIFT         (1UL<<0)
#define FAST_HAS_DEFAULT_RR   (1UL<<1)
#define FAST_DATA_MASK        0xfffffffcUL

uintptr_t getClassBits(Class kls) {
#if __LP64__
    typedef uint32_t mask_t;
#else
    typedef uint16_t mask_t;
#endif

    return ((const struct {
        /* struct objc_class */
        Class isa;
        Class superclass;

        /* struct cache_t */
        void *bucket_t;
        mask_t mask;
        mask_t occupied;

        /* struct class_data_bits_t */
        uintptr_t bits;
    } *) (__bridge const void *) kls)->bits;
}
```

This is recreating the structure format from `objc-runtime-new.h`, without all of the additional C++ overhead.

Once you have the bits for a class, simply compare it it with `FAST_IS_SWIFT` (e.g. `bits & FAST_IS_SWIFT`), and you should have your answer.

Comment: This did in fact change with the new ABI. The header now defines two flags. `#define FAST_IS_SWIFT_LEGACY  (1UL<<0)` and `#define FAST_IS_SWIFT_STABLE  (1UL<<1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Swift class names are prefixed with the name of the module. If one uses:

```
NSStringFromClass(SomeClass.self)
```

The result will be

```
MyApp.SomeClass
```

For my purpose, this works perfectly.

Comment: This is not true. Any Swift class annotated with @objc can have a prefix-free name. Also Swift's internal class names can be wax more complex than `A.B`.